# Transform between two occupancy grids

Tags: ros, navigation, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Is there a node available that subscribes to 2 occupancy grids (one is static the other one is created by hector_mapping), aligns them and publishes a transform between the two? I tried with mapstitch but the lack of information makes it complicated...

Why do I want that?
I am flying in a partially known environment. Therefore, a static map is used by move_base to compute a global path. In the meantime, I am creating a map with hector_mapping in order to compare it to the static map at the end of the process. Without any link between the two, the drifting between the maps prevent me from navigating after a while.

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224085/transform-between-two-occupancy-grids/) by [quentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/24914/quentin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2016-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've made some changes to mapstitch and used it quite successfully at RoboCup 2015 for online stitching of maps between two robots and creating merged maps. The version we used is in the [hector_mapstitch](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/mapstitch/tree/hector_mapstitch) branch.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1